# Python - HTTPRedirectHandler doesnt always get redirects

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using urllib2's HttpRedirecthandler to get the redirects of a url. The code looks like this:

```
import urllib2, cookielib

class HTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl):
        newreq = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request(self,
            req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl)
        if newreq is not None:
            self.redirections.append(newreq.get_full_url())
        return newreq



def getListOfRedirectUrls(adUrl):
    urlList = []

    h = HTTPRedirectHandler()
    h.max_redirections = 100
    h.redirections = [adUrl]

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(h)
    response = opener.open(adUrl)

    for redirect in h.redirections:
        urlList.append(redirect)

    return urlList
```

This works great for the majority of urls.  However, from time to time, it only gives me and first url and not the final page (or any in between).  For example, the ad link :

'http://trc.taboola.com/wtffunfact/log/3/click?pi=/&ri=4c376c94a4413aaace150a3cd2b9d902&sd=v2_b935da3ff37d8b8efc9f1aeaf46df13b_3932b8b5d26526ed68d78d4ca0b1c52d_1403183649_1403183649_CN6AAQ&ui=3932b8b5d26526ed68d78d4ca0b1c52d&it=video&ii=~~V1~~-2280573428682392386~~Uno41aIn9FS4V6KLu4hReNH33hC7jIMtL3ZKEwlHBjLt20WtOFlYyBFp19r7BzDGoDxni1tDH9vJwwB-9GbnkA&pt=home&li=rbox-h2v&redir=http://livingwelltrends.com/3/?src=tabn&query=ad3&net=desktop&ad=food7&utm_source=taboola&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=wtffunfact&p=jmedia-sc&vi=1403183649792&r=2'

just returns that url, but when I paste the url in a browser, it sends me to another page.  How do I get that final page programatically?  I tried using urlopen

```
var = urllib2.urlopen(url)

print var.geturl()
```

But this doesn't give the final landing page as well.  The redirect handler works well for most URLs so I dont know what the issue is for the ones that don't.  Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you try module `requests` - it redirects url as default and it has `response.history` with urls visited during redirections.

Comment: I tried importing requests and doing "response = requests.get(url)" but response.history returns an empty list.

Comment: I checked this url - it is redirected by JavaScript :) So `urllib`, `urllib2`, `requests` will not work with this. You need some browser simulator with JavaScript like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) if you really need it

Comment: `newreq` has a `url` string but no `get_full_url` function for me